# Macos Mojave: mactex installed > /bin/sh: mtxrun not found?

Tags: context, mactex

I am a complete newbie with latex. I just installed mactex. I am running a make file which uses context and in the log output is says: `/bin/sh: mtxrun: command not found`

Also when I run `context --version` it says `zsh: command not found`.

I can see in Tex Live Utility that `context` is installed.

I am not sure what to link in this case or is this even a linking issue or are is there an installation step that I have missed. I can open and run texshop.app and that seems to work but it is not accessible in my terminal.

Comment: Did you install `context` when installing `mactex`.

Comment: context is definitely installed on my computer but it seems that nothing is accessible through my terminal? Is there a special way to set this up that I should be aware of? I know how to link files in my zshrc filte but in this case I don't know what to link to since there are so many related libraries. Also my gola is to use context with pandoc and in pandoc when I run my make file the log file states that mtxrun is not found which seems to be some type of utility related to context from what i understand.

Comment: @molleweide Did you run `setuptex` to add the ConTeXt executables to `$PATH`?

Comment: No I have not. I will look into that. Do you know where I can read the documentation for that, Henri? Is that the way one is "suppose" to add tex to path. It seems nothing is accessible in my path now. Now setuptex either.

Comment: Since you installed via MacTeX, make sure `/Library/TeX/texbin` is added to your `PATH` environment variable.

Comment: @AdamMaxwell that fixed my issue